# Images are not loading that are referenced in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, ember.js

images in are loading properly when I am running the application locally but even though images are appearing in the folder on Server but not being loaded in the Sources when I see them, in the same folder structure when ran locally they are being loaded - any help why would that happen? When even the folder contains the images.
Here are 2 images I am posting - can somebody please suggest me something why doesn't it load - thank you - the below image is taken from url of the app hosted on the server.
[image]

Here is the image from local url
[image]

Here is the folder that shows the images are in the folder - any help please. Basically they are there but not showing in the browser or in sources when we debug the browser - any help would be very very appreciated - please - thank you.
[image]

Comment: May you show the css? It’s likely the url is incorrect.

Comment: I think you should post the code that loads the images or the html, since the issue can be there.

Comment: Its an Ember Code and it will be converted into a big app.js file - before that all those files and everything would be converted - I am not sure how can I show you the code -Ember Code before conversion into js or after js conversion. I think Web-pack converts Ember files into js files - I am not very expert in it though - any help friend. But anyways the files are showing up only thing is they aren't accessible, and similar scenario works locally though - any help please? Thank you.

Comment: You can run the production version of the code, concatenated, minified, fingerprinted, etc. locally by running ember serve --prod Check if it works in that environment.

Comment: Another thing you can try is to build the debug version and put it on your staging server. You do this by deploying the result of ember build --environment="development" rather than ember build --environment="production". You will then have the files unminiified and unfingerprinted on your server, so that you aren't looking at gibberish in the devtools when looking at your deployed code.